# Possible values for continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[2,6]$, and the only solutions of the equation $f(x)=7$ are $x=2$ and $x=5$. If $f(3)=9$, then one of the following **CANNOT** be the value of $f(4)$

A) 9
B) 8
C)7.5
D)5

---

I found this on the exam book and it says the answer is 5. But how??? How on earth could we justify that? I tried so hard that finally, I'm asking it here.

This was my futile approach: Write
$$f(x)-7=\alpha(x-2)(x-5)$$ (Idk if this is possible because $f$ is only continuous not polynomial)
Even from this, I can only exclude $f(4)=7$ because it would imply $0=-2\alpha$.

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is meant to be solved by IVT as mentioned in the other answer, but...

if you're stuck on a problem like this, since it's multiple choice, you could try graphing:

$f(2)=f(5)=7$,

$f(3)=9$,

and a dashed line at $f(x)=7$ that you are not allowed to cross except at $x=2$ and $x=5$.

Then see if you can draw a continuous function for each of those possible values of $f(4)$. I'm not saying that "drawing" is a rigorous problem solving technique in general, but it would probably lead you to the right answer for this problem.

Trying this may also give you intuition for why IVT implies the answer.

Comment: "a dashed line at $f(x)=7$ that you are not allowed to cross except at $x=2$ and $x=5$." is what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: intermediate value theorem. $7$ is between $\ldots$ and $9$.

Comment: But the ivt is existence theorem on $x$ not on $f(x)$. I still did not get it. Forgive me for my ignorance.

Comment: You are told that $f(3)=9$. If $f(4)<7$, then what does IVT say must exist, which contradicts what is said in the question?

Comment: What would be that contradiction? Honestly, I have no idea. I've always used IVT to show the existence of root or the existence of some number $c$ that satisfy $f(a)\leq f(c)\leq f(b)$.

Comment: Yes, and if $f(4) \le 7$, then there exists $3 \le c \le 4$ with $f(c)=7$, since $f(3)=9 \ge 7 \ge f(4)$. But can there be such a $c$, according to the question?